# Why do we suppress the input when calculating the Norton/Thevenin resistance?

Tags: thevenin, norton

When we calculate the thevenin/norton resistance of a 1-port circuit, we suppress the independent inputs, be it voltage or current. But, my textbooks do not explain as to why we do this.

So my question is, why do we suppress the inputs?

Comment: Because you are only finding the resistance, the supply voltage/current becomes irrelevant, hence its removed for ease

Answer (score 0):

Thevenin/Norton equivalents are linearly equivalent, so they'll behave the same independent of other perturbations.  They can safely be ignored for the conversion, and will have the same overall effect on the modified circuit.  This is the basis for superposition.

Comment: Then, if I calculate the resistance **without** suppressing the inputs, I should still get the same result, yes?

Comment: Correct.  Or if you analyze both forms of the circuit with the same inputs.  Otherwise you've done something wrong.